# background image height cut

Tags: css, background-image

I´m trying to figure out why the background image on my a:selected class is being cut both bottom and top. I´ve tried assigning `height:!important;` and `min-height;` to `.main_menu ul li` and `.main_menu ul li a.selected`, but seems like something else is limiting the background image size (17x21px)

I wanted to provide an image, but since I´m new they won´t let me do so :(
The image is a circle and it´s being sliced bottom and top, just as it was to fit into a smaller container

Here´s the code, thanks for any suggestion!

```css
.menu_container{
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    margin-top: 220px;  
}
.main_menu ul { 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin:0px;
    list-style-type: none;  
}
.main_menu ul li {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:11px; 
    letter-spacing:4px;
    text-align:right; 
    line-height:35px;  
    list-style-type:none;
}
.main_menu ul li a  {
    padding-right: 25px;  
    text-decoration:none;  
    color:#999; 
} 
.main_menu ul li a.selected {
    color: #bc4c9b;
    font-weight:bold; 
    background: url(images/circle.gif) right center no-repeat;
    height: 35px!important;  
}   
.main_menu ul li:hover {
    text-decoration:none;  
    color:#999;  
    font-weight:bold;  
    background:url(images/circle_grey.gif) right center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: it would be nice if you put the whole thing in jsfiddle.net that would be easy to encounter the real problem

Comment: Hi, I tried css-validator, I´ll try this one as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try and rewrite the following rule:

```
.main_menu ul li a  {
    padding-right: 25px;  
    text-decoration:none;  
    color:#999; 
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked.Both `display:block;` and `display: inline-block;` Thanks :)

Comment: @eliana You could thank by formally [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer. That is quite an established (and nice, too) form of thanking here on SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey i think you can give to

anchor tag `display: inline-block;` or give to `line-height`

as like this

```
.main_menu ul li a{
display:inline-block;
line-height:35px;  
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works adding the display property either on `.main_menu ul li a` or `.main_menu ul li a.selected`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your background is attached to a anchor tag (.main_menu ul li a) and is therefor sized after font-size. To see the whole background file, you need to make anchor element to block or you can use padding.
Use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

or

```
display: block;
```

or use padding for .main_menu ul li a

Comment: Yes, you are right. `display:inline-block` solved the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define **display:inline-block;** in your **li a** see your updated css :-

```
.menu_container{
position: absolute;
float: left;
width: 270px;
margin-top: 220px; 

}
.main_menu ul { 
padding: 0px; 
margin:0px;
list-style-type: none;  
}
.main_menu ul li {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:11px; 
letter-spacing:4px;
text-align:right; 
line-height:35px;  
list-style-type:none;
}
.main_menu ul li a  {
padding-right: 25px;  
text-decoration:none; 
font-weight:bold; 
color:#999; 
   display:inline-block;
} 
.main_menu ul li a.selected {
color: #bc4c9b;
font-weight:bold; 
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/TXNfW.gif) right center no-repeat;
}   
.main_menu ul li a:hover {
text-decoration:none;  
color: #595959;  
font-weight:bold;  
background:url(http://i.imgur.com/5Ic6o.gif) right center no-repeat;
}
```

see the demo:- http://jsbin.com/agavid/13/edit

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that´s exactly what was missing :)